# CakePHP: Modularizing a Controller action that uses a Component for use in a Shell

Tags: php, shell, cakephp

I have a shell script that I want to send the same email as in the controller. The controller action uses the `SwiftMailer` component. However, Shells can't call controller actions, so I'm looking for a way to modularize this email-sending code so that it can be used by *both* my **shell** and my **controller**.

*Ideally* I would put this email-sending code in the `afterSave`, but once again, components can't be used in models.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this may not be the greatest idea, but you did say "**Any** ideas?" :)

Probably the most reasonable course of action would be to extract the mail-sending code in a separate library (in the [Lib folder](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html#the-app-folder)) and then change your component and shell to use it.

Whether this is possible with your code is the real question, which I guess only you can answer. If you don't know, you'll just have to try.

In any case, good luck!